# Alternativa para conversão de Word para HTML

Tags: html, cms, microsoft-word

Dou manutenção em um site que não tem CMS e frequentemente recebo solicitações do cliente pedindo para colocar um texto com uma formatação pré-determinada.

Geralmente esses textos vem no formato do .doc ou .docx do MS Word.

O problema é que são textos longos com diversas formatações, tabelas e espaçamentos que precisam ser respeitados.

Quando tento argumentar com o cliente que não consigo simplesmente copiar e colar o documento numa página Web, o cliente não entende, e cobra de mim agilidade.

Porém o processo, como muitos devem saber, é trabalhoso. Preciso geralmente usar uma ferramente para converter de Word para HTML, mas os resultados são péssimos e ainda geram trabalho para acertar estilos, concertar links e ajustar imagens.

Minha pergunta então é: Tem uma forma mais amigável de receber conteúdo dos clientes para criar páginas HTML, se não tenho recursos de CMS no site?

Talvez algum editor de textos que já crie um HTML mais limpo que o do Word na opção de Salvar como HTML?

Alguém tem problema semelhante?

Comment: Seria tipo [isso aqui](http://www.wysibb.com/)?

Comment: Realmente é complicado fazer isso, até onde sei não existe, isso porque  o código fonte que o word gera é muito sujo

Comment: Já experimentou o CKEditor? Ele inclui uma funcionalidade de ["colar do Word"](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pastefromword) (Nota: nunca experimentei de fato para ver qual a qualidade real da conversão)

Answer (score 2):

Não existe solução pronta para isso. As soluções de conversão sempre gerarão um código sujo e o resultado não é sempre confiável, até porque o próprio Word gera um código sujo nos seus documentos.

Como você tem que fazer isso frequentemente, você tem 2 opções: convencer o cliente a usar um CMS ou desenvolver um processador xml para converter os arquivos docx que ele mandar em um html limpo para o seu site. Arquivos .doc vão dar tanto trabalho que o melhor é converter pra docx e dps passar no processador.

[Aqui](http://www.jackreichert.com/2012/11/09/how-to-convert-docx-to-html/) tem um exemplo desse tipo de script com php. O exemplo é simplificado, mas é um bm ponto de partida. E [aqui](http://www.officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php) você acha informações sobre a estrutura do Office Open Xml.

Divirta-se!